# Moving and changing SVG text causes Internet Explorer 11 to ignore the mouse

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

http://jsfiddle.net/zzbar210/3/

I am testing this with IE 11.0.9600.17280. If I change the text box while moving the mouse around over the SVG area Internet Explorer stops responding to mouse events (clicking, movement) for the entire page, but I can still use the keyboard (typing, tabbing around). The only way I've found to get mouse control back is to refresh the page. Sometimes it will happen even if the mouse is not moving.

What is causing this? Is there a way to work around the problem?

```js
var pt;

$(document).ready(function(){

  pt = document.getElementById("layout_area").createSVGPoint();
  
  $("#layout_area").mousemove(function(event) {
    $("#position").html(event.clientX);
     
     // Convert x/y into SVG position
      pt.x = event.clientX;
      pt.y = event.clientY;
      var svg = $("#layout_area")[0]
      
      var matrix = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
      
      var pos_x = matrix.x
      var pos_y = matrix.y
      
      $("#position").append("<br />( " + pos_x.toFixed(3) + ", " + pos_y.toFixed(3) + " )");

      document.getElementById("text1_use").setAttribute("x",pos_x-200);
      document.getElementById("text1_use").setAttribute("y",pos_y-200);
  });
  
  $("#label_text").keyup(function() {
      document.getElementById("text1").textContent = $("#label_text").val().trim();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="label_text" />
<br />
<svg width="400" height="200" viewbox="0 0 400 200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="layout_area" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <defs>
    <svg id="Si19krjw36" viewBox="-200 -200 400 400" width="400" height="400">
      <text id="text1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 25pt; text-anchor: middle;" fill="#000000" x="0" y="0">text</text>
    </svg>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
  <use id="text1_use" x="-103" y="-84.09" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#Si19krjw36" />
</svg>
<br /><br />
<div id="position"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that suits my needs. The problem seems to involve the cursor being right on top of the text when it changes, so I added an invisible div on top of the SVG and changed the mousemove event to that div. The cursor becomes the pointer type instead of the "text" type (i-beam), and the page no longer freezes when the textbox is changed.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zzbar210/6/

```js
var pt;

$(document).ready(function() {

  pt = document.getElementById("layout_area").createSVGPoint();

  $("#cover").mousemove(function(event) {
    $("#position").html(event.clientX);

    // Convert x/y into SVG position
    pt.x = event.clientX;
    pt.y = event.clientY;
    var svg = $("#layout_area")[0]

    var matrix = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

    var pos_x = matrix.x
    var pos_y = matrix.y

    $("#position").append("<br />( " + pos_x.toFixed(3) + ", " + pos_y.toFixed(3) + " )");

    document.getElementById("text1_use").setAttribute("x", pos_x - 200);
    document.getElementById("text1_use").setAttribute("y", pos_y - 200);
  });

  $("#label_text").keyup(function() {
    document.getElementById("text1").textContent = $("#label_text").val().trim();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="label_text" />
<br />
<div style="position: relative; height: 200px">
  <svg width="400" height="200" viewbox="0 0 400 200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="layout_area" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <defs>
      <svg id="Si19krjw36" viewBox="-200 -200 400 400" width="400" height="400">
        <text id="text1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 25pt; text-anchor: middle;" fill="#000000" x="0" y="0">text</text>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" fill="white" stroke="black" />
    <use id="text1_use" x="-103" y="-84.09" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#Si19krjw36" />
  </svg>
  <div id="cover" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); height: 200px; width: 400px"></div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="position"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you might be running into [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796745/mouse-events-are-not-delivered-at-all-anymore-when-inside-an-svg-a-use-is-removed-from-the-dom).

The workaround that I found was to set `pointer-events: none` on all `<use>` elements.  In my case, I needed to handle mouse events on my `<use>` elements, so instead I placed `<rect>` elements above them and attached my mouse handlers there.

Sadly, it doesn't look like Microsoft will ever fix this...

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same issue, and as far as I can work out, it's a bug in IE11 under windows 7.  In my case I move the clicked SVG element into another group, but the same thing happens - no mouse events for the entire page thereafter.

I've tried many workarounds, including delaying the DOM change using setTimeout, handling the event at a higher level in the DOM, removing click handler before changing the DOM.  Still the same result.

I'd really like to know if you get anywhere with this.  I'll fill you in if I find a work around.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not alone in this problem. My actual code has this problem randomly if I quickly moved the cursor around and bashed on the keyboard. It took a while to condense it down into the repeatable example I posted. 

The problem seems to involve the cursor being on top of the text when it changes. My workaround is to add an invisible div on top of the SVG so the cursor isn't technically on top of the text anymore. Take a look at my posted solution for a working example. And thanks for looking in to it!

Comment: Ah, great idea.  I reported a bug to IE here https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1002841, having narrowed it down to a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7LukdL7x/7/.   My work-around internally is to $(g).hide() and then remove the object 20 seconds after the click using setInterval.  Add a new object in the other layer instead.  But your solution would be much cleaner.  I'll give it a try.